# Microsoft Entra Verifiable Credentials Admin API - Issuing Client Credentials Issue

Tags: azure, access-token, azure-ad-verifiable-credentials

I'm trying to connect to the Entra Verifiable Credentials Admin API based on the documentation found here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/verifiable-credentials/admin-api, however I can't seem to issue client credentials that are able to call the Admin API endpoints.

I'm creating an access token like so:

```
GET https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenant_id>/oauth2/token?<query_params>

Query Params:
client_id=<client_id>
client_secret=<client_secret>
scope=6a8b4b39-c021-437c-b060-5a14a3fd65f3/full_access
grant_type=client_credentials
```

The scope in the above call was found here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/verifiable-credentials/admin-api Calling the endpoint https://verifiedid.did.msidentity.com/v1.0/verifiableCredentials/authorities with the token returned from above returns the response:

```
"error": {
    "code": "token_validation.audience_invalid",
    "message": "The token does not contain the expected audience '0135fd85-3010-4e73-a038-12560d2b58a9,6a8b4b39-c021-437c-b060-5a14a3fd65f3'."
}
```

I also tried creating an access token using the MSAL library in .NET like this:

```
var app = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder.Create("<client_id>")
       .WithClientSecret("<client_secret>")
       .WithAuthority(new Uri("https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenant_id>"))
       .Build();

var result = await app.AcquireTokenForClient(new string[] { "6a8b4b39-c021-437c-b060-5a14a3fd65f3/.default"}).ExecuteAsync();

Console.WriteLine("Access Token: {0}", result.AccessToken);
```

The MSAL library throws an error if the scope doesn't end with `/.default`, so I switched what the Verifiable Credentials Admin API suggests to `6a8b4b39-c021-437c-b060-5a14a3fd65f3/.default`. Using the credentials output by the MSAL library to call the Admin API returns this error:

```
"error": {
    "code": "Unauthorized",
    "message": "Provided access token contains no wids.",
    "innererror": {
        "code": "token_validation.invalid_aad_access_token",
        "message": "Provided access token contains no wids."
    }
}
```

The Application Registration has the `Verifiable Credentials Service Admin.full_access` permission assigned and has been granted admin consent. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong or what I need to change to get an access token that's able to call the Verifiable Credentials Admin API.

Comment: Could you please confirm whether your granted permission type is **`Delegated`** or **`Application`**?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm in the same spot :/

Answer (score 1):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got below results:***

I have one Azure AD application and added **API permissions** as below:

[image]

Now I generated access token with same parameters as you like below:

```json
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenantID>/oauth2/token

client_id:client_id
client_secret:client_secret
scope:6a8b4b39-c021-437c-b060-5a14a3fd65f3/full_access
grant_type:client_credentials
```

**Response:**

[image]

When I used the above token to call authorities, I'm getting **same error** as below:

```json
GET https://verifiedid.did.msidentity.com/v1.0/verifiableCredentials/authorities
```

**Response:**

[image]

Now, I used **v2.0** token endpoint with **`/.default`** scope to generate the token like below:

```json
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenantID>/oauth2/v2.0/token

client_id:client_id
client_secret:client_secret
scope:6a8b4b39-c021-437c-b060-5a14a3fd65f3/.default
grant_type:client_credentials
```

**Response:**

[image]

When I used this token to call authorities, I got **same error** as below:

[image]

Note that, Client credentials flow works with only **`Application`** type permissions.

If your granted permission is of **`Delegated`** type, you need to use **interactive flow** like Authorization code, etc.... to get token.

To **resolve** the error, I generated token using **`authorization code`** flow with below parameters:

```
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenantID>/oauth2/v2.0/token

client_id:client_id
grant_type:authorization_code
client_secret:client_secret
scope:6a8b4b39-c021-437c-b060-5a14a3fd65f3/.default
code:code
redirect_uri:https://jwt.ms
```

**Response:**

[image]

When I used this token to call authorities, I got **response** with **`Status: 200 OK`** as below:

[image]

As I don't have any authorities, I got value as ***blank***. You can try the same in your environment by generating token using **Authorization code** flow.